# TestNG @BeforeClass initialization code not running before Test

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testng

I am writing test codes with Selenium, TestNG. I am trying to set some elements on the `@BeforeClass` section as I am repeating those actions on the same page. But I am getting null pointer exception. Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
public class RunTest {
private static WebElement user;
private static WebElement pass;
private static WebElement login;

@BeforeClass
public static void driveraBaglan() {
    //Driver is declared here. I removed it to give the simple code. 
    user = driver.findElement(By.id("user"));
    pass = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]"));
    statusMessage = driver.findElement(By.id("login-status-message")).getText();

}
@Test(priority=1)
public void loginNoInfo() {
        user.clear();
        pass.clear();
}
```

I get the null pointer error on `user.clear()` , `pass.clear()` and `login.click()` functions. All tests on the page runs on the same page. I don't want to use repeated "find element by id" tags on each test on the page.

Comment: Could you post the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag is run.
> @BeforeClass: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked
> ```

try to change the annotation

```
@BeforeTest
public static void driveraBaglan() {
    //Driver is declared here. I removed it to give the simple code. 
    user = driver.findElement(By.id("user"));
    pass = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]"));
    statusMessage = driver.findElement(By.id("login-status-message")).getText();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used **TestNG** but I do use **Junit**. Trying to replicate your example, I obtained the following exception:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/davide.patti/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/temp-testng-customsuite.xml

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestSO.loginNoInfo(TestSO.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

The reason was because, in my imported classes I was using the BeforeClass of Junit:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

and not of TestNG.

If your null pointer exception is the same, be sure that your imported classes are the correct ones:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this same issue by an accidental change I've done.

You may also get the null pointer exception on objects you are initializing in @BeforeClass or @BeforeTest, when you have a dilemma situation as below (where the class is set to as a disabled test class while having enabled test methods).

```
@Test(enabled=false)
public class TestClass{
    A a;    

    @BeforeClass
    public void doBeforeClass(){
      a=new A();
      //
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
       a.callMethod1();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
       a.callMethod2();
    }

}
```

Here, when you are running full-suite by putting `@Test(enabled=false)` only for the class, still the suite will run individual tests in the class since `@Test` annotations are present there. However, since `@BeforeClass` is not running for whole class, object 'a' is not initialized and will cause null pointer exceptions.

In such cases, the individual `@Test` annotations too need to be changed to `@Test(enabled=false)`

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to include alwaysRun = true, which implies that it was probably a misconfiguration of the groups somehow.

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
setup() { ... }
```